# Microsoft Fix It Registry issue

Tags: installation, registry, windows-server-2008-r2

I had a program that starts up a Windows Service when installed and deleted that Windows Service when uninstalled. However it refused to uninstall after I modified the installer by accident (my fault!). I couldn't even remove it from Programs and Features as it kept throwing an error 2715. I found this article that had a FixIt program: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/program_install_and_uninstall

Using that, I managed to finally remove the program itself. Now however, when I try installing and uninstalling it again (to test my changes), the Windows Service that's attached doesn't get removed. In fact, it continues running. I checked the registry and indeed the key for the service is still there after the uninstall. I would need to manually stop it and do a sc delete to get rid of it. Any idea on how I can solve this?

Edit: I am able to replicate the issue on another computer. What I do is, I install the program there, and use the Fix It tool to remove it. Once this is done, I can easily replicate the issue as the service is never deleted after uninstalling. It works fine prior to this.

Answer (score -1):

Some guesswork here because there's not enough info....

Eroor 2715 is a Windows Installer error, and I suspect it's related to you running a program (as you describe it) to start and stop services. I'm guessing that you run it as a cuatom action, and on uninstall you attempt to run it but it's missing because it's been uininstalled.

So:

1. That fixit cure is not for a broken MSI (which yours is) - it's for fixing corrupt registry data that prevents uninstall, not fixing a broken MSI uninstall.
2. You don't need to run code to start and stop and delete services. Most MSI-building tools have support to the the Windows Installer functionalty that does this for you, so stop doing it!
3. A more specific answer is difficult without knowing what you are using to build your MSI with, and how you're running your program, but the signs point to you running the program after it's been removed, and even if you get the program running properly there's no way to tell whether it is correct without seeing the code. But 2 is what you should be doing anyway.

Comment: The MSI works fine though. I've tried it on two other computers and it works fine. What I did was I rebuilt the installer that I had modified before uninstalling.

Comment: The MSI in fact does not work fine if you sometimes get that 2715 error! The issue appears to be related to running that program of yours, which is unnecessary. Maybe a timing issue, who knows? Again, in the absence of a verbose log of the uninstall and further info it's another guess, but Windows Installer will start and stop services without you needing to write code and so the vast majority of setup developers simply tell MSI to start/stop/delete any services.

Comment: When I try to uninstall using the MSI, I would get a popup asking to stop the service and try again. I need this to be automated so I inserted a custom action to do so before the MSI tries to validate it. Again I'd like to stress that the MSI works. I have now tested it on 2 VMs and 3 other dev PCs. I've also managed to replicate the issue where if I were to install the program and use Microsoft FixIt to uninstall it (as if there was an issue with it) it will cause this problem. This was done on another PC where all I did was install it, then proceeded to uninstall it using Microsoft FixIt.

Comment: I can't really say much more without repeating myself, and I don't know if your popup was a files-in-use type of dialog or something else. The "repeating myself" part is that all installer tools except Visual Studio that generate MSI files have support for ServiceControl and ServiceInstall actions that do all of this and it just works, no code, no custom actions. It's also possible that your service is broken if it is not responding properly to the protocol messages/events related to stopping, shutting down anmd taking too long.